# Spring MVC SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST causes continuous invalid sessions

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring MVC App and I have an issue with invalidated sessions.

The app performs AJAX requests that are all authenticated/tied to a session (hold a JSESSIONID)

So here's what happens. Let's say I'm in the app authenticated with a session.  If I go into Tomcat and invalidate that session, then the next time an HTTP request gets made, Spring forwards me to the login page.  Once I login again, Spring authenticates me fine, but then a number of my AJAX requests get HTTP 403 errors, continuously.

If I go into the HTTP Headers of the requests that get the 403s, I notice they have 2 JSESSIONIDs, one of the authenticated session, the other one of a session that holds **only** this attribute:

```
SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST   DefaultSavedRequest[<OLD URL>]
```

So these sessions are not authenticated sessions so they are causing Spring to return a 403.

The issue is that this persists until I kill the browser (on some mobile devices that doesn't even work, and I have to go into settings to clear the browser cache).

Any suggestions?

this is a big problem because it's happening when Sessions invalidate themselves because of TTL, and we're stuck with users who get booted out, log back in and still get 403s, forever, until they clear the cache.

Comment: Another note - it looks like when I log back in Spring is attempting to re-execute any URL that is attached to a SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST and those are the 403's that I'm getting.  Is there any way to turn that functionality off? (the SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST one I'm referring to )

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that Spring Security invalidates the existing session when you login and creates a new one, copying the contents of the old one across. This is intended to create a new session identifier to avoid session fixation attacks. You can try disabling this feature to see if it is related to your problem. It sounds like these are the two sessions you are talking about.

However if there are two JSESSIONID headers in the request then it sounds like a problem on the client side. You should work out why your client is sending two values. Also, it sounds like there may be an issue with Tomcat on the server side if you are still able to read the contents of the previously invalidated session.

Also check that Tomcat isn't sending two JSESSIONID values in the login response. There was an issue ages ago where it was doing just that, but it's unlikely you are running such an old version of Tomcat.